# Prove that a closed ball $B$ is closed and bounded in $(C[0,1], d^*)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be the set of all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb R$ and let $(C[0,1], d^*)$ be the metric space defined as $$d^*=sup\{|f(x) - g(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}$$  Let $$B = \{f: f \in C[0,1] \land d^*(f, 0) \le 1\}$$ where $0$ denotes the constant function from $[0,1]$ into $\Bbb R$ which maps every element to $0$.

**Prove that the closed ball $B$ is closed and bounded in $(C[0,1], d^*)$.**

I know this is bounded because $(\exists r > 0)(d^*(f_1,f_2) \le r)(\forall f_1,f_2 \in B)$ if we chose $r = 1$ as defined in $B$, but I'm not sure how I would prove this is closed.  I would assume showing that every sequence of functions converges to a function in $B$, or the compliment is open, etc.

Comment: Does $C[0,1]$ mean you are talking about continuous functions only? It changes a lot your problem...

Comment: I added that in the description.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're in a metric space $(X,d)$, any set of the form $D = \{x: d(p,x) \le r \}$, wheer $r > 0, p \in X$ is closed and bounded. Nothing special about $C([0,1])$. You can show the complement is open: if $d(q,p) > r$ then show using the triangle inequality that $B(q, d(q,p) - r)$ is disjoint from $D$.

Comment: I don't understand how I would show that they're disjoint with the triangle inequality.  If $B(q,d(p,q) - r)$ is an open ball of radius $d(p,q) - r$, then $B(q,d(p,q) - r) = \{x : x \in X \land d(q,x) < d(p,q) -r \}$.

So $d(x,q) < d(p,q) - r \land d(p,x) \le r$

Comment: Suppose $q'$ is in $B(q, d(p,q)-r) \cap D$. Then $d(q,p) \le d(q,q') + d(q',p) < d(p,q) - r + r = d(p,q)$, contradiction.